# Kriging - spatial autocorrelation analysis

Tags: arcgis-pro, kriging, variogram

[I'm reading a paper](https://doi.org/10.3390/su12072974), where semivariogram analysis was done using kriging to calculate spatial autocorrelation of building hights.

The paper says:

> As can be seen from Figure 3, the building in the main urban area of
> Chenzhou indicates a stable building height at a distance of 167.22 m
> (dash line), thus the grid size was set at 200 * 200 m.

[image: Figure 3:]

I don't have strong knowledge about krigig and semivariograms, but I can't understand how authors calculated the value `167.22 m` since distance should be mesured on the `X axis` and I can't understand how could one caulculate this value even on the `X axis` as well. To me it seems like authours wrongly analysed `Y axis` instead of `X axis`?

Am I missig something?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the authors and the referees have both messed up. It looks like they've guessed where their fitted variogram flattens out. They may have read it off from their fitted model parameters, but they don't give any details on the kriging model form or fitted parameters as far as I can see. There's also no explanation of what the "binned" and "averaged" markers are.

Having read off 1.6722 off the Y axis (with spurious precision there - can you believe the last decimal points?), converted to 167.22 because the axis scale is 10^-2, they've interpreted this as a distance of 167m and then decided to use a grid of 200m for some reason.

The 167.22 is the variogram at infinite distance, which for certain conditions is the variance of the data. (see Properties in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram). Its not a spatial length, its a (mean) difference in squared height of building, in this case.

I don't see any mention of using variograms for the things this paper is doing in the references in this section.

They seem to be using variograms to decide on a grid size, via "The more even the building height is within the grid, the more appropriate the grid size is." But "evenness" of height is *low* variance, not maximum. At small distances, buildings are similar heights (all towers in the centre, all two-storeys in the suburbs perhaps). This is why the variogram increases.

So I think the horizontal line (the sill) is nonsense for what they are doing, but somehow, perhaps more by luck than judgement, they've come up with a small grid cell size. At 200m distance (between 0.146 and 0.293 on the X axis - what's with the stupid axis label values?), the fitted variogram is still very low, showing small variance in height at 200m distance.

In summary, as a referee I'd want this corrected for resubmission, and stuff like this shouldn't get through publication anyway...

Comment: Thank you. I had simmilar thoughts on this. Anyway, 1.6722 * 10^-2 = 0.016722 not 167.22 ...

Comment: The axis legends look like multiplicatives, `v * 10^-2` and `h * 10^-3` (there's a dot) so `0.2 = h * 10^-3` - solve for `h` -> `h=0.2 * 10^3` -> `h=200`. But yeah, its not clear either way.